# Error while adding contact to Google API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public static Contact CreateContact(ContactsRequest cr)
{
    Contact newEntry = new Contact();
    // Set the contact's name.
    newEntry.Name = new Name()
    {
        FullName = "Elizabeth Bennet",
        GivenName = "Elizabeth",
        FamilyName = "Bennet",
    };
    newEntry.Content = "Notes";
    // Set the contact's e-mail addresses.
    newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
    {
        Primary = true,
        Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
        Address = "liz@gmail.com"
    });
    newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
    {
        Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
        Address = "liz@example.com"
    });
    // Set the contact's phone numbers.
    newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
    {
        Primary = true,
        Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
        Value = "(206)555-1212",
    });
    newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
    {
        Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
        Value = "(206)555-1213",
    });
    // Set the contact's IM information.
    newEntry.IMs.Add(new IMAddress()
    {
       Primary = true,
       Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
       Protocol = ContactsProtocols.IsGoogleTalk,
    });
    // Set the contact's postal address.
    newEntry.PostalAddresses.Add(new StructuredPostalAddress()
    {
       Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
       Primary = true,
       Street = "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy",
       City = "Mountain View",
       Region = "CA",
       Postcode = "94043",
       Country = "United States",
       FormattedAddress = "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View",
    });
    // Insert the contact.
    Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
    ContactsService GContactService = null;
    GContactService=  new ContactsService("My Project 55318");
    GContactService.setUserCredentials("binal.p1391987@gmail.com", "abc@223133");

    ContactsFeed contactFeed = new ContactsFeed(feedUri, GContactService);
    // contactFeed.Insert(newEntry);
    Contact createdEntry = cr.Insert(feedUri, newEntry);
    Console.WriteLine("Contact's ID: " + createdEntry.Id);
    return createdEntry;
}
```

This line throws exception "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

```
Contact createdEntry = cr.Insert(feedUri, newEntry);
```

Can any one have full code example for adding contact details in gmail in asp.net?

I need to add name and phonenumber in gmail ?

Comment: What is `ContactsService` here? `GContactService.setUserCredentials` sounds like Java rather than C#. This doesn't look like the kind of Google API we normally generate... Ideally, show a [mcve] rather than a large but incomplete example.

Comment: A 401 Unauthorised error usually means that you do not have the correct login credentials, please confirm they are correct.

Comment: You either supplied the wrong credentials, or you didn't include them, or you included them in the wrong way. Check the API docs for what's required. P.S. If I was you I wouldn't have written my credentials into the code I placed onto a **public** website. It's only a matter of time before someone attempts to use it. Assuming that _is_ your real google password, then you should change your password A.S.A.P.